# Monodromy element: Why that name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, terminology, singularity, hopf-algebras

Let $(H,R)$ be a quasitriangular Hopf algebra, i.e. $R$ is a choice of an universal $R$-matrix for the Hopf algebra H. (You can find a definition of the term *quasitriangular Hopf algebra* [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasitriangular_Hopf_algebra).).
One calls the element $Q:=R_{21}\cdot R_{12} \in H \otimes H$ the **monodromy element** of the quasitriangular Hopf algebra $(H,R)$.

**Questions**

- Why is $Q$ called that way?
- Is it related to the monodromy group? Or to any other concept presented on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy)?

Comment: It may have something to do with the Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knizhnik%E2%80%93Zamolodchikov_equations